# yocto, using meta-toolchain: linux/errno.h missing

Tags: c, embedded-linux, yocto, toolchain, errno

I have built a toolchain using 'bitbake meta-toolchain' (Yocto Morty) and installed it at /opt/poky/2.2.1/.

When I try to manually build any user code containing #include , then build breaks on missing linux/errno.h file.

```
. /opt/poky/2.2.1/environment-setup-cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi 
$CC main.c 
In file included from /opt/poky/2.2.1/sysroots/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/errno.h:35:0,
             from main.c:2:
/opt/poky/2.2.1/sysroots/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/bits/errno.h:24:26: fatal error: linux/errno.h: No such file or directory
# include <linux/errno.h>
                       ^
 compilation terminated.
```

I searched /opt/poky/2.2.1/ for "linux/errno.h" and found nothing. Am I missing something? I have thought that meta-toolchain builds toolchain installation which is self-contained.

Comment: have you before build for any image (maybe core-image-minimal) for your machine? Your sysroot doesnt seem to be filled at all if such basic includes are missing.

Comment: Yes, I have built an image which was extending core-image-minimal (my rootfs is about 120 MB).

Comment: My compressed toolchain is about 74MB and it contains some errno.h files: `/opt/poky/2.2.1/sysroots/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/src/debug/glibc/2.24-r0/git/stdlib/errno.h
/opt/poky/2.2.1/sysroots/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/src/debug/glibc/2.24-r0/git/include/errno.h
/opt/poky/2.2.1/sysroots/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/sys/errno.h
/opt/poky/2.2.1/sysroots/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/bits/errno.h
/opt/poky/2.2.1/sysroots/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/errno.h`